# How to assert a null object in dolphindb?

Tags: function, null, assert, dolphindb

I can create a null objects in dolphindb like

```
x = 00i;
y = 00l;
```

but when I run

```
00i == 00l
eqObj(00i,00l)
```

they are all return true，I can't make a distinction between two null value or objects, is there any function to do that?

what I want :

```
x = 00i
x == somefunction(somevalue)
```

to assert x is a null value in correct type

Answer (score 0):

```
def identicalNullObj(a, b){
    return a == b && a.type() == b.type()
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.